# Facebook news feed, cant find server

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used the code on this site: http://blog.carduner.net/2010/05/26/authenticating-with-facebook-on-the-command-line-using-python/

I am trying to get a news feed from the users facebook account.
I have created an application on facebook and put the application ID and Secret into the variables in the program.

For some reason it gets to:

```
while ACCESS_TOKEN is None:
    httpd.handle_request()
```

and it opens firefox with an error "Firefox can't find the server at 127.facebook.com."
any ideas of why its trying to go to 127.facebook.com?
I thought it was supposed to go to "127.0.0.1:8080"

The user has allowed the app.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 127.0.0.1 with 'localhost'. That works for me. This is a low-priority bug in Facebook : http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82131